Грамотно ли выражение: строить будущее- дело семейное
Чат- бот в Телеграмм говорит, что выажение " сроитьсчасть- дело семейное" грамотно , допустимо. Так ли это?

Предложение корректное:
Строить будущее — дело семЕйное.
Пояснение

Сравнить: Строить будущее — семейное дело.

Инверсия определения семейное  в заданном предложении делается для его логического подчеркивания ударением в конце предложения.

По грамматике это двусоставное предложение: строить — подлежащее, выраженное инфинитивом,  дело — сказуемое. Такая грамматическая модель предложений есть у Розенталя, пункт 2:
2. Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым, если оба 
они выражены неопределенной формой глагола (инфинитивом) 
или если один из главных членов выражен формой 
именительного падежа существительного, а другой — 
неопределенной формой глагола: О решённом говорить — 
только путать (М. Г.); Долг наш — защищать крепость до 
последнего нашего издыхания (П.); 


Вероятно, бот не учитывает тире, тогда получается глагольное словосочетание с инверсией, а не предложение: Строить будущее  дело семейное.


Можно попробовать добавить связку это и посмотреть, как он будет реагировать: Строить будущее — это дело семейное.
